# After installing SSD in 2009 iMac I only see a black screen

Tags: imac, ssd, screen, startup

The computer chimes, and when I press any key like the option or R keys to enter recovery or the Startup Disk Manager, nothing happens. I tried to reset the SMC to no avail.

I have a 3TB portable HDD with a bootable install partition of Sierra I would like to install on the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. The DisplayPort connector came undone.

Answer (score 0):

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). Resetting this would be the first thing I'd do:

1. **Power off your iMac**
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.** In your case it probably won't boot normally, but then power off again and try starting up again with the <kbd>Option</kbd> key down to see if Startup Disk Manager appears.

Let us know how you go.

Comment: I reset the PRAM, but the screen is still black when I press the [option] key. Could it be a problem with the screen connector?